# Deploying node.js to azure web app Via Github Actions, I keep failing my build due to some error that i quoted and screenshot below. Please & Ty

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, azure, github-actions

["npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!

> core-js@3.21.1 postinstall /home/runner/work/team-mario-p2-frontend/team-mario-p2-frontend/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js-pure@3.21.1 postinstall /home/runner/work/team-mario-p2-frontend/team-mario-p2-frontend/node_modules/core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):

[image]

Comment: There is no error in your description. Please don't post error messages as images. Post them as text. What's unclear with the error message? It shows you the file, the lines and the reason. The variables aren't defined. It has nothing to do with Azure or GitHub Actions.

Comment: I did post the error the picture is so you can see exactly what is going on. The program runs perfect everywhere else and the variables are defined thats why this is wierd. Please give me some solutions

Comment: Again, post the error message as text, not as image. Add a [mcve] of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is that you're using different npm versions locally and in actions.

If this is the issue, then you can resolve it by specifying a different node version with the [setup-node action](https://github.com/actions/setup-node). For example, specifying node 16 means you'll get npm 8.

Specifying node 12, on the other hand, will lead to npm 6. npm 6 is also what causes lockfile version 1 while npm 8 uses lockfile version 2.

Sample:

```yaml
uses: actions/setup-node@v3
with:
  node-version: 16
```